# Filter NSArray with 2D-NSDictionaries using NSPredicate

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsarray, nsdictionary, nspredicate

i have a `NSArray` containing some `NSDictionaries` which themselves also include a `NSDictionary`.

```
NSDictionary *dict1 = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"cover" forKey:@"type"] forKey:@"image"];
NSDictionary *dict2 = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"cover" forKey:@"type"] forKey:@"image"];
NSDictionary *dict3 = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"back" forKey:@"type"] forKey:@"image"];
NSDictionary *dict4 = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"cover" forKey:@"type"] forKey:@"image"];

NSArray *myArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:dict1, dict2, dict3, dict4, nil];
```

is there a way to filter `myArray` for all Image-Dictionaries where the type is f.e. "cover" using a NSPredicate?

tried predicates like

```
predicateWithFormat:@"(SELF.image.type == %@)", @"cover"]
```

or

```
predicateWithFormat:@"(image.type == %@)", @"cover"]
```

but without success.

thanks in advance! leave a comment if something is unclear

### // edit

so

```
NSPredicate *p = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"image.type == %@", @"cover"];
```

is working. but in my case i want to sort out size == original. what i did is

```
NSPredicate *p = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"image.size == %@", @"original"];
```

but then my app crashes with

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSSymbolicExpression length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

and pointing to my `filteredArrayUsingPredicate` method. i cannot see any difference between type and size. see my NSLog of my Array here

```
 (
        {
        image =         {
            height = 1500;
            id = 4e5808765e73d607350059b4;
            size = original;
            type = poster;
            url = "someurl";
            width = 1000;
        };
    },
        {
        image =         {
            height = 750;
            id = 4e5808765e73d607350059b4;
            size = mid;
            type = poster;
            url = "someurl";
            width = 500;
        };
    },
```

anybody knows why it crashes when i try to use size instead of type ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code worked for me:

```
NSDictionary *dict1 = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"cover" forKey:@"type"] forKey:@"image"];
NSDictionary *dict2 = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"cover" forKey:@"type"] forKey:@"image"];
NSDictionary *dict3 = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"back" forKey:@"type"] forKey:@"image"];
NSDictionary *dict4 = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"cover" forKey:@"type"] forKey:@"image"];

NSArray *myArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:dict1, dict2, dict3, dict4, nil];

NSPredicate *p = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"image.type == %@", @"cover"];
NSLog(@"%@", [myArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:p]);
```

Comment: indeed, it does. no idea what went wrong in my code. thought i tried this predicate (the simplest one ;) ) at first. thank you!

Comment: Well, if the code in your question is the real code you tested, then you were looking for the string @"poster", but you don't have that in your dictionaries - you only have @"cover" and @"back". So an empty result is actually correct. :-)

Answer (score 7):

SIZE is a reserved keyword.

Found at the bottom of the [Predicate Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pSyntax.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001795-CJBDBHCB):

The following words are reserved:

AND, OR, IN, NOT, ALL, ANY, SOME, NONE, LIKE, CASEINSENSITIVE, CI, MATCHES, CONTAINS, BEGINSWITH, ENDSWITH, BETWEEN, NULL, NIL, SELF, TRUE, YES, FALSE, NO, FIRST, LAST, SIZE, ANYKEY, SUBQUERY, CAST, TRUEPREDICATE, FALSEPREDICATE